# IGlobalInterfaceTable::RegisterInterfaceInGlobal returns E_NOTIMPL

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com, atl

Does anyone know why `IGlobalInterfaceTable::RegisterInterfaceInGlobal` might return `E_NOTIMPL`?

I'm using ATL's `CComGITPtr` and simply assigning it to a COM pointer.  The assignment, in turn, calls the following ATL code:

```
HRESULT Attach(_In_ T* p) throw()
{
    if (p)
    {
        CComPtr<IGlobalInterfaceTable> spGIT;
        HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
        hr = AtlGetGITPtr(&spGIT);
        ATLASSERT(spGIT != NULL);
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;

        if (m_dwCookie != 0)
            hr = spGIT->RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal(m_dwCookie);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;

        return spGIT->RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(p, __uuidof(T), &m_dwCookie);
    }
    else
    {
        return Revoke();
    }
}
```

Apparently that last call to `spGIT->RegisterInterfaceInGlobal` results in `E_NOTIMPL`.

I'm performing the assignment in the context of an in-proc Explorer extension, and I'm doing it on the main UI thread.

Also, I'm not sure if this is related, but I get the same error when trying to use `RoGetAgileReference` (on Windows 8.1), doing something like this (with an `IShellItemArray`):

```
HRESULT hr;
CComPtr<IAgileReference> par;
hr = RoGetAgileReference(AGILEREFERENCE_DEFAULT, IID_IShellItemArray, psia, &par);
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: There are 99% chances that this is related to the IShellItemArray implementation on Windows 8.1. It's probably missing some necessary code (proxy / stub, etc.) to be put in the GIT (RoGetAgileReference will try to use the GIT too). Not sure there's anything you can do, Microsoft will not be super interested by a product that's out of mainstream support for 3 years. Why do you want to put that in the GIT?

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the info. When a selection change occurs in Explorer, I'd like to call some functions on the selected shell item array on some background threads.

Comment: You can pass PIDLs (an arrays of) instead of ShellItems. PIDLs are designed to cross everything including machine boundaries.

Comment: Well the `IShellItemArray` pointer still works fine from different threads/apartments.  I was just trying to do things properly by calling the appropriate marshaling functions.

Comment: I'm not surprised this particular one works, it's just a collection of things

Comment: On a positive note, an `IShellItem` obtained from the `IShellItemArray` can successfully be used with the marshaling functions.